# ++ Operator on pointers

Tags: c, pointers, increment

My CS course is taking a bit of a turn from Java to C. I'm busy going over pointers at the moment and I have come across that the ++ operator for incrementing doens't work when dereferencing. This is more just a curiosity question than anything else. Just not used to the pointers concept just yet. Am I just doing something wrong or is it something to do with pointers?

For example:

```
*pointer++; Will not increment the value.
*pointer+=1; Will increment the value.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
*pointer++;
```

is equivalent to

```
*(pointer++);  // pointer is incremented
```

and not to

```
 (*pointer)++;  // pointee is incremented
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 5):

When you want to increment the value you have to make sure you use parenthesis.

```
(*pointer)++;
```

Answer (score 4):

`*pointer++` increments the `pointer` variable, not value pointed by it.

```
int array[4] = {3,5,7,9};

int *pointer = array;

// *pointer equals 3

*pointer++;

// *pointer now equals 5
```

Comment: @Jim Cover the code under the mouse then press `CTRL + K`, else you can use `<pre> </pre>` ..

Answer (score 2):

`*pointer++;` is almost equivalent to:

```
*pointer;
pointer = pointer + 1;
```

**Why its so?**

In expression `*pointer++;`, `++` is postfix operator, so fist `*` deference operation performed then `++` increments value of `pointer` (and not increments value).

Whereas  `*pointer += 1` is just equivalent to:

```
*pointer =  *pointer + 1;
```

that increments value pointed by `pointer`.

Answer (score 2):

This has to do with precedence of the operators: post-increment `++` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`, while `+=` has lower precedence [in the table of operator precedences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). That is why in the first example `++` is applied to the pointer which is dereferenced afterwards, while in the second example `+= 1` is applied to the result of dereference.

Comment: I notice late, But you explained very nicely conceptually!  ... I really like your answer.